# Is it permissible to discuss and use worldly things inside the mosque?

Tags: halal-haram, masjid

I have a feeling that discussing or conducting certain activities (such as studying, world related other things etc) related to the world isn't good while you're inside but what I wanted is a confirmation with facts if possible.

The reason is why because, I saw a man came into the mosque and said to few youngsters like me; who were discussing their education related stuff inside the mosque. They were probably doing some homework and discussing certain matters related to it, I assume. But this elderly person came to them and said its prohibited nor is it good to do such worldly things inside the Kingdom of Allah (jalla jalaaluhu). He also said that if you don't believe ask some of your Moulavee's for confirmation. But as I heard, he did not give any facts.

Is it prohibited or not favored to do such worldly things like studying, having academic discussions and doing homework inside the mosque?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with talking about worldly matters in the masjid, as this was done by the Prophet and his companions.

It's collected in Sahih Muslim, in the 'Book of Masajid and Places of Prayer' from Simaak bin Harb:

I asked Jabir bin Samurat: "Did you sit with Rasolullah?"
نَعَمْ كَثِيرًا كَانَ لاَ يَقُومُ مِنْ مُصَلاَّهُ الَّذِي يُصَلِّي فِيهِ الصُّبْحَ أَوِ الْغَدَاةَ حَتَّى تَطْلُعَ الشَّمْسُ فَإِذَا طَلَعَتِ الشَّمْسُ قَامَ وَكَانُوا يَتَحَدَّثُونَ فَيَأْخُذُونَ فِي أَمْرِ الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ فَيَضْحَكُونَ وَيَتَبَسَّمُ
He said: **"Yes, many (times)."**

**He (Rasolullah) used to sit at the place where he prayed the morning (subH) prayer till the sun rose.  He would stand, and they would talk about times of Jahiliya, and they would laugh while (the Prophet) only smiled.**

And this narration is authentic in Sahih Muslim.

As you can read, the Prophet and his companions AT THE PLACE OF PRAYER, would talk about times of jahiliya, pre-islamic era.  And they would laugh and the Prophet would smile.

This happened many times, as Jabir said he sat with Rasolullah "kathir."

But there's one thing you should be considerate about.  Make sure you're not disturbing others.

Comment: Thank you for your broad explanation. But what you said is that they've spoken about things relating to Islam though those are worldly matters. What I specifically asked is about conversing things relating to studies, gossiping.. etc

Comment: They would talk about times of Jahiliya.  Times before Islam.  There are some other hadiths that I just thought about in which girls were singing about pre-islamic wars betwen aws and khazarj in the presence of the Prophet in his home which was connected to the masjid.  Also, a hadith about Ethiopian slaves doing war games in the masjid.  Therefore, it's not forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

Masjids are made for purpose of worshipping Allah, and not for worldly gossip.

A hadith states:

> The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   said: ‘There will come a time when people will sit in circles in the
>   mosques and they will have no concern except this world. Allaah has no
>   need of them so do not sit with them.’”

So it is better to avoid talking about worldly matters in masjids.

for detailed answer, you can consult:

http://islamqa.info/en/4448

Comment: This hadith is not authentic.  One of its narrator, Ahmed bin Bakr, was rejected by Daraqutni and declared his reports as strange.  And another narrator, Zaid bin al-Hoban was not accurate.

Comment: This is a saheeh hadeeth even though al-Bukhaari and Muslim did not narrate it. Al-Dhahabi said in al-Talkhees that it is saheeh.”

Comment: al-Bukhari and Muslim didn't narrate it was bc they considered Ahmed bin Bakr as unreliable, same as Daraqutni.  Three MAJOR hadith scholars who lived several hundred years before al-Dhahabi and were part of collecting hadith. al-Dhahabi wasn't a hadith collector.

Answer (score 0):

Today we were going to Masjid for doing our assignment our concern was, we will be able to pray Salah on time and with jamah, other we will miss it.
some of mu fellows said No it is not good to do worldly things in Masjid!
then i gave them some examples, and while finding some facts and figures i came to this page.

1st reply to your question is 100% true and exact.
the Hadith is 2nd reply is un-authentic some people have replied well for.

Conclusion
As per my knowledge and underatanding of DEEN, Masjid is not "just" for salah or qirat etc. it is the CENTER of Muslim Society!
we can talk we can laugh we can study other stuff science etc.

try to have meeting with a scholar of no sect, who follow Quran o Sunnah coz some of scholar will give yoi fatwa as their imam said so go for JUST Quran o Hadith & Sahaba 
1st Comment have very good answer !

Comment: This looks like a comment on answers rather than an answer. We are a Q&A site not a typical internet forum, answers here should be focussedm on answering the actual question, well elaborated and any claim should be supported by an evidence. Also read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Do not talk any worldly matters at masjid never and ever 
It will eat up the good deeds like how the fire eating up the fire wood
You can do islamic preaching , do dhikr , reading Quran , sharing Islamic knowledge one another without disturbing other deeds

Comment: An evidence supporting your claims would be helpful to improve your post. (See [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing reading or studying worldly things in masjid is Haram as long as it does not disturb  the people in the masjid, and also Islam uncourages learning both worldly and here after usable knowledge, and Quran is mother of all knowledge as we know, so there is no harm in studying in the masjid as long as what you are studying is halal and doesn't contain pictures of any living creatures